# "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'logger')" - Durable Function Activity

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have the following activity function:

```
 [FunctionName("LoadSubscriptionAnalytics_Activity")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> RunActivity([ActivityTrigger] ILogger log
        )
        {                              
            log.LogInformation("Activity function");
        }
```

Log.LogInformation fails with error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'logger')

The logger works in my orchestrator function:

```
 [FunctionName("LoadSubscriptionAnalytics_Orchestrator")]
        public static async Task<List<Task<IActionResult>>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            var outputs = new List<Task<IActionResult>>();
         
            log.LogInformation("Orchestrator function");
            
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<Task<IActionResult>>("LoadSubscriptionAnalytics_Activity", null));          
           
            return outputs;
        }
```

Why is this dependency injection not working?
I am using Functions V2 with .Net Core 3.1

Comment: What is the stack-trace of the exception? What code is calling your `RunActivity` method and is responsible for passing `log: null` ?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve it, had to pass a context object -IDurableOrchestrationContext context from the orchestrator so that the activity function could detect it as a parameter. My code is:

**Orchestrator**

```
[FunctionName("LoadSubscriptionAnalytics_Orchestrator")]
        public static async Task<List<Task<IActionResult>>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            var outputs = new List<Task<IActionResult>>();

            log = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(log);
            log.LogInformation("Calling LoadSubscriptionAnalytics_Activity");
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<Task<IActionResult>>("LoadSubscriptionAnalytics_Activity", context));

            log.LogInformation("Done !");
           
            return outputs;
        }
```

**Activity**

```
[FunctionName("LoadSubscriptionAnalytics_Activity")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> RunActivity([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext activityContext, ILogger log
        )
        {
            //This works               
            log.LogInformation("Activity function");
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: The signature of CallActivityAsync is: public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult> CallActivityAsync<TResult> (string functionName, **object input**); Are you sure that passing context as the input solved the problem? It seems the input object is not used in your code though.

Answer (score 0):

- `LogInformation` is an extension-method for `ILogger`, defined in `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll`.
- Because it's an extension-method rather than a *real* instance method, when it's invoked it's the same as a `static` method call, and the .NET runtime will not check that the subject/instance reference is `null` or not - so you *don't* get a `NullReferenceException`.

  - Which *can* be useful, actually - I have my own utility library with a syntactically-succinct extension-method alternative to `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`:

    ```
    // Declaration:
    public static Boolean IsSet( this String str ) => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( str ):

    // Usage:
    String x = null;
    Console.WriteLine( x.IsSet() ); // Prints "false" with no NullReferenceException
    ```
- So in your case, when `log.LogInformation("Activity function");` runs, the `log` argument  to `RunActivity` is `null`.
- I assume `log` is intended to be optional - so use `?.` to skirt around it - or if it's required then throw your own `ArgumentNullException` exception:

```
[FunctionName("LoadSubscriptionAnalytics_Activity")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> RunActivity( [ActivityTrigger] ILogger log )
{
    log?.LogInformation("Activity function");
}

[FunctionName("LoadSubscriptionAnalytics_Activity")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> RunActivity( [ActivityTrigger] ILogger log )
{
    if( log is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(log) );
    log.LogInformation("Activity function");
}
```

- As for why the `log` parameter's argument is `null` in the first place - have you configured your DI container correctly in `ConfigureServices`? I'll admit I'm not too familiar with Azure Durable Functions - but in .NET in general DI is only set-up for constructors, not static methods - though some environments do allow DI use for static method parameters.